# How to properly load nested JSON as a nested table, using React + typescript and bootstrap@5.3.2

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, bootstrap-5

I am trying to load the nested json properly on the Orders.tsx page. I am trying to display all past orders. My Api returns me a correct list of all cart objects in json format. Each cart has 3 fields, cartItem, cost and delivery date. Now, each cartItem consist of product and product quantity. Now, each product has a bunch of different fields. I am hereby attaching all the required files.
My problem is that whenever i load it, nothing loads, react developer tool still finds react element tree, if i go back to my userProfile, from where i called this function, it doesnt load properly

Orders.tsx (the commented mode is alternative i wrote, before asking chatgpt many times)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import UserContext from "../components/UserStateDetails";
import OrderDetail from "../components/OrderDetail";

interface ProductDataType {
    itemId: number;
    imageSrc: string;
    productName: string;
    price: number;
    deliveryDate: string;
    isOffer: boolean;
    offer: number;
}

interface CartItemDataType {
    id: number;
    products: ProductDataType;
    quantity: number;
}

interface CartDataType {
    cartId: number;
    checkedOut: boolean;
    cartItems: CartItemDataType[];
    cost: number;
    deliveryDate: string;
}

interface userDataType {
    allCarts: CartDataType[];
}

// const Orders = () => {
//  const { userIdGlobal } = useContext(UserContext)!;
//  const [data, setData] = useState<userDataType>({ allCarts: [] });

//  const fetchUserDetails = async () => {
//      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/user/orders?userId=${userIdGlobal}`);

//      if (response.ok) {
//          const retrievedData = await response.json();
//          console.log(retrievedData);
//          setData(retrievedData);
//      } else {
//          const errorMessage = await response.json();
//          console.error(`Cannot retrieve: error ${response.status} with message ${errorMessage}`);
//      }
//  };

//  useEffect(() => {
//      fetchUserDetails();
//  }, [setData]);

//  return (
//      <>
//          <section id="page-header">
//              <h2>Orders</h2>

//              <p>Past orders history</p>
//          </section>
//          <div className="Order-container">
//              {/* ((dataObj, index) => (
//                  <tr key={index}>
//                      <th scope="row">{index}</th>
//                      <td>
//                          <OrderDetail id={index} productName={dataObj['']} price={dataObj['price']} quantity={dataObj['']}/>
//                      </td>
//                      <td>Otto {}</td>
//                      <td>@mdo</td>
//                  </tr>
//              ))} */}
//              <table className="table">
//                  <thead>
//                      <tr>
//                          <th scope="col">#</th>
//                          <th scope="col">Order items</th>
//                          <th scope="col">Deliverty date</th>
//                          <th scope="col">Cost</th>
//                      </tr>
//                  </thead>
//                  <tbody>
//                      {data ? (
//                          data.allCarts.map((cartObj, index) => (
//                              <>
//                                  {console.log('first stage cleared')}
//                                  <tr>
//                                      <th>{index+1}</th>
//                                      <td>
//                                          {cartObj.cartItems.map((cartItem, index2) => (
//                                              <table className="table-sm">
//                                                  <thead>
//                                                      <tr>
//                                                          <th scope="col">#</th>
//                                                          <th scope="col">Product name</th>
//                                                          <th scope="col">Price</th>
//                                                          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
//                                                          <th scope="col">Calc</th>
//                                                      </tr>
//                                                  </thead>
//                                                  <tbody>
//                                                      <tr>
//                                                          <th scope="row">{cartItem.id}</th>
//                                                          <td>pname {cartItem.products.productName}</td>
//                                                          <td>price {cartItem.products.price}</td>
//                                                          <td>quantity {cartItem.quantity}</td>
//                                                          <td>
//                                                              calcFirst {cartItem.products.price * cartItem.quantity}
//                                                          </td>
//                                                      </tr>
//                                                  </tbody>
//                                              </table>
//                                          ))}
//                                      </td>

//                                      <td>placeholder {cartObj.deliveryDate}</td>
//                                      <td>placeholder {cartObj.cost}</td>
//                                  </tr>
//                              </>
//                          ))
//                      ) : (
//                          <p>Loading...</p>
//                      )}
//                      <tr>
//                          <th>-1</th>
//                          <td>Sent through component</td>
//                          <td>Otto</td>
//                          <td>@mdo</td>
//                      </tr>
//                      <tr>
//                          <th>-2</th>
//                          <td>Sent through component</td>
//                          <td>Thornton</td>
//                          <td>@fat</td>
//                      </tr>
//                      <tr>
//                          <th>-3</th>
//                          <td>Sent through component</td>
//                          <td>Thornton</td>
//                          <td>@twitter</td>
//                      </tr>
//                  </tbody>
//              </table>
//          </div>
//      </>
//  );
// };

const Orders: React.FC = () => {
    const { userIdGlobal } = useContext(UserContext)!;
    const [data, setData] = useState<userDataType>({ allCarts: [] });
  
    const fetchUserDetails = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/user/orders?userId=${userIdGlobal}`);
  
        if (response.ok) {
          const retrievedData = await response.json();
          setData(retrievedData);
        } else {
          console.error(`Cannot retrieve: error ${response.status}`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred while fetching data:", error);
      }
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchUserDetails();
    }, []); // Use an empty dependency array since this effect doesn't depend on any variables.
  
    return (
      <>
        <section id="page-header">
          <h2>Orders</h2>
          <p>Past orders history</p>
        </section>
        <div>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Order items</th>
                <th scope="col">Delivery date</th>
                <th scope="col">Cost</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data ? (
                data.allCarts.map((cartObj, index) => (
                  <tr key={index}>
                    <th>{index + 1}</th>
                    <td>
                      <div> {/* Wrap the cart items in a <div> */}
                        {cartObj.cartItems.map((cartItem, index2) => (
                          <OrderDetail
                            key={index2}
                            id={cartItem.id}
                            productName={cartItem.products.productName}
                            price={cartItem.products.price}
                            quantity={cartItem.quantity}
                          />
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>{cartObj.deliveryDate}</td>
                    <td>{cartObj.cost}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              ) : (
                <tr>
                  <td colSpan={4}>Loading...</td>
                </tr>
              )}
              {/* Remove the hard-coded rows at the bottom */}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };

export default Orders;
```

OrderDetails.tsx

```
import React from "react";

interface OrderDetailProps {
  id: number;
  productName: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;
}

const OrderDetail = ({ id, productName, price, quantity }: OrderDetailProps) => {
  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Product name</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">Calc</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{id}</th>
          <td>pname {productName}</td>
          <td>price {price}</td>
          <td>quantity {quantity}</td>
          <td>calcFirst {price * quantity}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default OrderDetail;
```

Example fetched data (JSON):

```
[
    {
        "cartId": 1,
        "cartItems": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "products": {
                    "itemId": 3,
                    "itemName": "Choco loco",
                    "price": 20.21,
                    "isOffer": false,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "deliveryDate": "2022-12-10",
                    "offer": 0.0
                },
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ],
        "checkedOut": true,
        "cost": 20.21,
        "deliveryDate": "2022-12-10"
    }
]
```

All the above, tried chatgpt for fixing it, but i think the problem is related to the dom tree and myself started react a week before havent understood completely to debug it. I am majorly following bootstrap models

Comment: The question has been solved. Apparently, i misunderstood the JSON formatting and had created a wrong datatype interface. Thus, it wasn't loading. After changing the type which would correctly map the data, the problem was solved.